# OpenCV "The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows"

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I get this error when I try to import `numpy`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('image.jpg',1)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitkey()
cv2.destroyAllWwindows()
```

when I run attribute `imread` is not working

> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:636: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage

Python version: 3.6

OpenCV version: 3.4.1

matplotlib version: 2.2.2

Comment: `cv2.imshow` is not implemented. Print the output of function `cv2.getBuildInformation()` and in the result search for `GUI`.

Comment: https://files.fm/u/jk4rv86z#/view/getBuildInformation.txt

Comment: If you look under the heading `GUI`, you'll see `VTK support: NO`. This means your OpenCV was not built with GUI support. Follow an online guide and build opencv from source with GUI support.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same issue too. Despite they were installed before, I've installed them again via:

```
pip install opencv-python 
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

and problem solved.

Comment: Installing  `opencv-contrib-python` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem under python v3.7.9

I typed `pip list` and I had opencv-python-headless version 4.4.0.44

I looked under GUI tag and VTK support: NO

I typed the command @Samet suggested and now I have

```
opencv-contrib-python           4.4.0.46
opencv-python                   4.4.0.46
opencv-python-headless          4.4.0.44
```

It is working now but I don't know if I should leave 'opencv-python-headless'. As @Fabio Baldissera said he only installed opencv-contrib-python and it worked but I don't know if you would want to end up with opencv-python and opencv-contrib from two different versions, I would **not** recommend it.

I'm able to show a RTSP stream now.