# (-2:Unspecified error) OPENCV (4.4.0) ERROR

Tags: python, opencv

I'm getting an error (shown below) when I run my program. Does anybody know how to solve it?

```
#Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

#When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: I am getting this error.How can I fix it?]

Comment: Can I ask if your operating system is Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: It's Windows 10

Comment: (base) C:\Users\EMRE>sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. (I think cuz of my operatins system is Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the others as before:

1. `pip3 uninstall opencv-python`
2. `pip3 uninstall opencv-contrib-python`
3. `pip3 uninstall opencv-contrib-python-headless`

And then only install the first two:

1. `pip3 install opencv-python==4.4.0.46`
2. `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46`

This may further help you: [OpenCV "The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783177/opencv-the-function-is-not-implemented-rebuild-the-library-with-windows)

Comment: When I uninstalled (opencv-contrib-python-headless) I got: "NO MODULE NAMED AS CV2",then I installed it again and I just got the error in the picture I shared :( it looks really complicated :'(

Comment: I uninstalled them and installed again with your order, but i got same error..

Comment: @ms.bigdatax Try my further updates answer.

Comment: You are marveolous ! I do not know whether "Error" is my bff , but you are :D  Thank you so much!

Comment: @ms.bigdatax No worries, opencv can be infuriating sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Reinstalling `opencv-python` doesn't solve anything.

Found out that two files are missing from the folder:

- `age_net.caffemodel`
  [image: Missing file]
- `gender_net.caffemodel`
  [image: Missing file]

Adding both files in the project folder solves the issue.